# Find Shortest Path in a weighted Directed Graph in SQL

Tags: sql, graph, shortest-path, weighted

I want to compare the performance of Neo4j and SQL in the following problem:

I have the following network topology:

[image: ']

Using SQL, I want to store the devices as nodes in a table and the weighted edges between nodes in another table. Then, find the shortest path between 2 nodes. Can I do this in SQL? I only find this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path?view=sql-server-ver15)
but the article said that the SHORTEST_PATH implementation finds an unweighted shortest path.

Suggestions please.

Comment: As a person with hands-on experience with creating a graph on top of a relational database, I'm wondering.. what's the point? A *native* graph db like Neo4j is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Totally right. I want to make a comparison with SQL to prove that Neo4j is better and faster.  I wish to give me ideas instead. I want to evaluate the performance of Neo4j. Many thanks @Graphileon